# Restart timer with bloc architecture Flutter

Tags: flutter

This is generic class for timer

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class QCountDown extends StatefulWidget {
  const QCountDown({
    super.key,
    this.preText = '',
    this.value = 10,
    required this.onComplete,
  });

  final Function onComplete;
  final int value;
  final String preText;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _QCountDownState();
  }
}


class _QCountDownState extends State<QCountDown> {
  late Timer _timer;
  late int _start;

  void startTimer() {
    const oneSec = Duration(seconds: 1);
    _timer = Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
      (Timer timer) {
        if (_start == 0) {
          setState(() {
            timer.cancel();
            widget.onComplete();
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _start--;
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }

    void restartTimer() {
    _timer.cancel();
    startTimer();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _start = widget.value;
    startTimer();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
          text: widget.preText,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
          children: [TextSpan(text: '$_start')]),
    );
  }
}
```

Using this timer in bloc architecture and want to restart when it has to restart.

This is how calling timer

```
 showCounter() {
      return Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const Text('Did not get OTP? '),
          if (_showCountDown) const Text('Resend OTP after '),
          if (!_showCountDown)
            GestureDetector(
              child: const Text('Resend OTP'),
              onTap: () {
                _action('RESEND');
              },
            ),
          if (_showCountDown)
            QCountDown(
              onComplete: () {
                setState(() {
                  _showCountDown = false;
                });
              },
            )
        ],
      );
    }
```